# ¿Cómo hacer que mi clase toogle funcione en boostrap select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, select

Hace poco descargue y empecé a utilizar el boostrap select y todo funciona correctamente, salvo por el detalle de que una vez que lo abra ya no se cierra ni aunque le de clic al select o fuera del select, se queda abierto el resto del programa. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna clase o forma de cerrar ese select de boostrap. Para hacer que se abriera utilicé una clase:

Código para usar el select y permitir que se abriera.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
    $(".selectpicker").click(function () {
         $(this).addClass("open");
    });

});
```

Codigo html del selector

```
<select class="selectpicker"  multiple data-max-options="3">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Yo intente agregar `$(this).addClass("close");`  abajo de `$(this).addClass("open");` para ver si esa clase me cerraba las opciones, pero no funciono.

**Actualizacion**

Ya agregue la clase `toggle` pero sigue sin funcionar al momento de cerrar las opciones y tiene todas las dependencias que en teoría debería de necesitar para poder funcionar, estoy usando el plugin de silvio moreto

Codigo completo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vista/plugin/forms_pago/form_pago1/archivo.css">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">




<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Contacto</li>
    <li>Banco</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>



    <h2 class="fs-title">Informacion de Contacto</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Paso 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" />
    <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese sus Apellidos" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ingrese su correo electronico" />

    <select class="selectpicker"  multiple data-hide-disabled="true" >
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>




<button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente">

  Siguiente &nbsp <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> 

</button>



  </fieldset>



  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Informacion Bancaria</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Paso 2</h3>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_asociado" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre Asociado" />
    <input type="text" name="clabe" placeholder="Ingrese la CLABE" />
    <input type="text" name="banco" placeholder="Ingrese el Banco" />
    <input type="text" name="numero_tarjeta" placeholder="Ingrese el numero de tarjeta" />


<button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" >

  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> &nbsp  Anterior  

</button>


<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Enviar" onclick="continuar3();"  >

      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> &nbsp Enviar  

</button>



  </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="vista/plugin/forms_pago/form_pago1/archivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".selectpicker").click(function () {
         $(this).addClass("open");
    });


</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No añadas el evento jQuery onClick. Simplemente carga las librerías y utiliza la clase .selectpicker como tienes en el código html y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución de mi problema era muy sencillo, solo tuve que agregar la siguiente linea de código abajo de jquery.

Código que se debe de agregar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```